# Filter Json with javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to create a function that takes a date as argument that will display the data only. This is to map it with `leaflet`.

The time series data looks like this:

(it's in `JSON`)

```
Time - DetectorID
0    -  5
1    -  3
2    -  4
```

and the `geoJson` that the data is mapped against is as follows:

```
var myGeojsonData =
{
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          144.829434,
          -37.825233
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Area": "Combined Entry MVT on Grieve Pde, West Gate Fwy North Ramps, Grieve Pde Byp Start EB between Grieve ",
        "IDnumber": "DetectorID"
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },...etc
```

I am trying to take the data from the time series with the following `javascript` code.

```
function selectdata(Time,timeseriesdata) {
    output = timeseries.Time["(Time)"]
    return output(time)
}
```

Comment: Could you please add timeseriesdata sample data in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the pandas function to transform this to Json from a dataframe.